# Given is relation $R$. What is $R^T, R^2, R^+, h_{\text{sym}}(R)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $V = \left\{1,...,5\right\}$ and there is relation $R$ on $V$
>
> $$R=\left\{(1,1),(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(5,4)\right\}$$
>
> What is $R^T, R^2, R^+, h_{\text{sym}}(R)$?

Hi maths people I need info how these notation is correct for learn it because not sure I understand all notation good.

---

I check on internet $R^T$ mean transpose of relation $R$ is defined: $R^T= \left\{(y,x) | xRy\right\}$

That's why I write $R^T=\left\{(1,1),(5,1),(4,2),(3,3),(1,4),(2,4),(4,5)\right\}$

---

$R^2$ I don't know..

---

Definition of $R^+ = \bigcap\left\{S \subseteq A \times A \mid S \text{ is transitive and  } R \subseteq S\right\}$

I understand that I need take all pair from $R$ which keep it transitive?

$R^+ = \left\{(1,1), (5,1)\right\}$

---

Definition $h_{\text{sym}}(R)=\bigcap\left\{S \subseteq A \times A \mid S \text{ is symmetric and } R \subseteq S\right\}$

I take all pair from $R$ as long as it's symmetric?

$h_{\text{sym}}(R)= \left\{(1,1), (3,3), (2,4),(4,2)\right\}$

---

Please help for understand it I do it good or not?

Comment: $R^2$ would be the Cartesian product of the set with itself: $R\times R=\left\{ (x, y) | x,y\in R \right\}$.

Comment: Since $h_{\text{sym}}(R)$ is the intersection of some supersets $S$ of $R$, it is itself a superset of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2$ = { (a,b) : some x with aRx, xRb }

For $R+$ add as few pairs as possible to R to make R transitive.

For sym(R) add as few pairs as possible to R to make R symmetric.